# Select which shows just 2 last created records for each contract

Tags: sql, oracle, select

I've got a temporary table where are around 2000 contract codes. Each contract has 1 installment each month, but last month were generated duplicity installment records.
I need to select just last two records for each contract which have generated 2 installments in one month.
For example:

```
Select * from TABLE_XY
where code = '112233' and rownum <= 2
order by creation_date desc;
```

This select shows what I need but just for one code.

I have temporary table (name it temporary_table) where I have stored all contracts.
I am not sure if I explained it well :) If you need more ino pls let me know
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if I understand what you want to do. If you need to extract the codes related to a contract, stored in the temporary table could make a JOIN or put a select in the IN of the code

```
Select * from TABLE_XY where code in 
(select code from temporary_table where id_contract = ?¿) and rownum <= 2 order by creation_date desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

This should help

```
select * from (
  select
    t.*,
    count(code) over (partition by code, to_char(creation_date, 'YYYY-MM')) as cnt,
    to_char(creation_date, 'YYYY-MM') as creation_month,
    row_number() over (partition by code, to_char(creation_date, 'YYYY-MM') order by creation_date desc) as rnum
  from table_xy t
  )
where cnt > 1 and rnum < 3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try giving row number to code which was repeated for last month with order for that date.

```
select * from
(Select a.*,row_number() over(partition by code order by creation_date desc) rn from TABLE_XY a)
where rn <= 2;
```